# CGImageRef or CGImageMaskCreate performance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Wondering if you guys ever face the scrolling performance issue while using the codes as follows.

```
- (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```

Ok, so basically the codes above are doing image masking which I found from this site.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html#comment-47347

And I've successfully integrate it to my project which bringing me some poor performance issue while scrolling the table view.

From what I've suspect is because each and every time the cell will keep "re-render" the image masking and cause the poor performance.

Comment: You suspect correctly

Comment: Hey @borrrden, do you have solution on this?

Comment: Create the masked image somewhere else

Comment: What does you mean by create the masked image somewhere else @borrrden, its good if you can tell more :) thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the masked image every time you scroll the tableview and get a new cell?  Why not just create them all and store them in an array somewhere, or if there are too many then create them asyncronously using dispatch_async (just don't forget to do the actual UIImageView assignment on the main thread).